# Regular expression is not working (Java)

Tags: java, regex

I want to make a regular expression that matches the form **(+92)-(21)-1234...**. I made this program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // A regex and a string in which to search are specifi ed
    String regEx = "([+]\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-\\d+";
    String phoneNumber = "(+92)-(21)-1234567890";

    // Obtain the required matcher
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

    if (matcher.matches()) {
        System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form (+xx)-(xx)-xxxxx..");
    }

} //end of main()
```

The regular expression i created like starts with the bracket(**(**), +**[+]**, two numbers(**\d{2}**), bracket close(**)**), a dash(**-**), start bracket(**(**), two numbers(**\d{2}**),  bracket close(**)**), a dash(**-**) and then any number of digits(**\d+**). But it is not working. What i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You should escape the ( and ) brackets, they are used for grouping in regular expressions, and you also have to escape the + sign.

Comment: @pushy: I believe that using `[+]` is okay, but `\\+` would be clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The regular expression i created like starts with the bracket(()

No, it starts with a grouping construct - that's what an unescaped `(` means in a regular expression. I haven't looked at the rest of the expression in detail, but try just escaping the brackets:

```
String regEx = "\\([+]\\d{2}\\)-\\(\\d{2}\\)-\\d+";
```

Or a nicer (IMO) way of saying that you need the +

```
String regEx = "\\(\\+\\d{2}\\)-\\(\\d{2}\\)-\\d+";
```

Comment: This is the fun part I love about regexes in Java - there always are a lot more backslashes than valid characters.

Comment: Hmm it means if i just want to use + not [+], then i should use \\ before + like **\\+**. Any character that i use in the regEx must start with \\, like **\\(** for opening bracket and **\\)** for closing bracket and **\\+** for plus. And the other way is to use **[(]** and **[)]** for open and close brackets as suggested by the **Amit Bhargava** and others. Am i right?

Comment: @Basit: it's not *any* character... it's any character that has a *special meaning* in a regular expression. I wouldn't normally use `[...]` as that is usually used for "match any character in this set".

Comment: HHmm ok now i got it. You mean to say that we use + in regular expression to append any number of characters so i must use \\ before it(\\+), same for ( and ) as they are use to make groups in regular expressions. But 'a' or any alphabet has no special meaning in regular expression so i can use just a,  no need this time \\a. Am i right now?

Comment: @Basit: Exactly. Indeed, for some letters you'd find that meant something entirely different - such as `\d` meaning "digit". (It's important that you understand that `\\` in a Java literal just means `\` in the regular expression itself, btw.)

Answer (score 2):

Escape the parentheses and the dashes

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the parantheses (as Jon already mentioned they create a capturing group):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     // A regex and a string in which to search are specifi ed
     String regEx = "\\([+]\\d{2}\\)-\\(\\d{2}\\)-\\d+";
     String phoneNumber = "(+92)-(21)-1234567890";

     // Obtain the required matcher
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
     Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneNumber);

     if (matcher.matches()) {
         System.out.println("Phone Number Valid");
     } else {
         System.out.println("Phone Number must be in the form (+xx)-(xx)-xxxxx..");
     }

}
```

Output:

Phone Number Valid

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex is

```
[(][+]\\d{2}[)]-[(]\\d{2}[)]-\\d+
```

You just needed to put your brackets between [  and ].

Answer (score 0):

if the plus symbol is always there you could just write `\\+`, if it may or may not be there, `\\+?`. You should escape all regex-specific characters like this

```
String regEx = "\\(\\+\\d{2}\\)-\\(\\d{2}\\)-\\d+";
```